# How to do GET request via AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

I added directories `AFNetworking` and `UIKit+AFNetworking` to project manager.
I use latest library 3.0.4

After I imported file `AFNetworking.h` in my class file `.m`.
I found a lot examples how to make request to url, but information is old.

How to make GET request to URL and get data from server?
Now function `AFHTTPRequestOperation` was removed.

This is first time working with libraries in xcode, I am beginner.

Comment: You don't need third-party libraries for that, check out NSURLSession.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com/"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                        path:@"http://google.com/api/pigs/"
                                                  parameters:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    // Print the response body in text
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
[operation start];
```

=============================================

You can also use AFHTTPRequestOperation:

```
NSOperationQueue *networkQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

networkQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] 
initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", string);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"%s: AFHTTPRequestOperation error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
}];
[networkQueue addOperation:operation];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but `AFHTTPRequestOperation` is not supported

Comment: Do you use only `#import "AFNetworking.h"`?  Compilator does not see object `AFHTTTPClient`

Comment: Note this solution is not functional in AFNetworking 3.0, see Chanchal's answer below for a working snippet.

Comment: Why is it necessary to initWithBaseUrl but then also provide the full path when using requestWithMethod?

Answer (score 82):

For AFNetworking 3.x:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: The best answer as the questioner talks about AFNetworking 3.0+. The other above solutions are not supported by AFNetworking 3.0 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
please try below answer.
+(void)callAFWS:(NSDictionary *)dict withURL:(NSString *)strUrl 
withToken:(NSString *)strToken withBlock:(dictionary)block
{
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:strToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",WebserviceUrl,strUrl] parameters:dict progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    if (!responseObject)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dict setObject:ServerResponceError forKey:@"error"];
        block(responseObject);
        return ;
    }
    block(responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:ServerResponceError forKey:@"error"];
    block(dict);
}];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With AFNetworking 3.0 you need to make request as under:

```
NSURL * urlStr = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];

NSDictionary *dictParameters = @{@"user[height]": height,@"user[weight]": weight};

AFHTTPSessionManager * manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];


[manager GET:url.absoluteString parameters:dictParameters success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"PLIST: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(void)postDatabyAF{

NSString *url;

NSDictionary *dict;

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:
                              NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

[manager POST:url parameters:dict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {

    NSLog(@" operation.responseData  %@",operation.responseData);
    NSLog(@" operation.response %@",operation.response);
    NSLog(@"statusCode %ld",operation.response.statusCode);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    if (error) {

    }
    else{


    }
}];
```

}