# How can I call multiple API at the same time in View controller background Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need call two API at the same time in view controller. One API (API 1) called every 5 seconds, and other API (API 2) called at the same time, but it will take 1 minute (Long time to get the response).

My issue is when I call API 2 of that time unable to get response of API 1. API 1 is waiting for complete API 2 Response, after that I got the response of API 1. I want API 1 response. API 1 is no need to wait for API 2 response.

How can I can implement the logic?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: call 2 api in background thread **dispatch_async** or  add in Queue

Comment: use blocks for callback .do call API 2 on success callback  of API 1.

Comment: Provide code, What you tried?

Comment: You can use a `DispatchGroup`, but your scenario isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking ? Get some example of this. Search on google.

Have a look on these:

1. https://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial
2. [How to do GET request via AFNetworking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34639175/how-to-do-get-request-via-afnetworking)
3. [How to sign up through Rest API using AFNetworking 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591313/how-to-sign-up-through-rest-api-using-afnetworking-2-0)

If you don't want to use this, use dispatch_async.

Call 1 API:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

 //api call 

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     //UI operations, when you receive data. 

 });

 });
```

Call API 2:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

 //api call 

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     //UI operations, when you receive data. 

 });

 });
```

It won't hamper another process. Thanks!

Comment: Suggesting the use of a 3rd party Library is not the best/ideal answer. If you have a way to do it in Native swift then please update your answer

Comment: You can not implement better something with your own try within short time than Afnetworking because it is developed by group of people.